# How to search efficiently in a nested collection in a functional way

Tags: scala

I'd like to find the indices (coordinates) of the first element whose value is 4, in a nested `Vector` of Int, in a functional way.

```
val a = Vector(Vector(1,2,3), Vector(4,5), Vector(3,8,4))
a.map(_.zipWithIndex).zipWithIndex.collect{
    case (col, i) =>
        col.collectFirst {
            case (num, index) if num == 4 =>
                (i, index)
        }
}.collectFirst {
    case Some(x) ⇒ x
}
```

It returns:

```
Some((0, 1))
```

the coordinate of the first 4 occurrence.

This solution is quite simple, but it has a performance penalty, because the nested `col.collect` is performed for all the elements of the top Vector, when we are only interested in the 1st match.

One possible solution is to write a guard in the pattern matching.  But I don't know how to write a guard based in a slow condition, and return something that has already been calculated in the guard.

Can it be done better?

Comment: Are you forced to work with a `Vector[Vector]` or can you change the data structure?

Comment: It can be changed, what is interesting is the algortihm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive maybe? 
If you insist on using `Vector`s, something like this will work (for a non-indexed seq, you'd need a different approach):

```
   @tailrec
   findit(
     what: Int, 
     lists: IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Int]], 
     i: Int = 0, 
     j: Int = 0
   ): Option[(Int, Int)] = 
     if(i >= lists.length) None
     else if(j >= lists(i).length) findit(what, lists, i+1, 0)
     else if(lists(i)(j) == what) Some((i,j)) 
     else findit(what, lists, i, j+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing you can to without changing the algorithm is to use Scala streams to be able to exit as soon as you find the match. Streams are lazily evaluated as opposed to sequences.

Just make a change similar to this

```
a.map(_.zipWithIndex.toStream).zipWithIndex.toStream.collect{ ...
```

In terms of algorithmic changes, if you can somehow have your data sorted (even before you start to search) then you can use `Binary search` instead of looking at each element.

```
import scala.collection.Searching._

val dummy = 123

implicit val anOrdering = new Ordering[(Int, Int, Int)]{
  override def compare(x: (Int, Int, Int), y: (Int, Int, Int)): Int = Integer.compare(x._1, y._1)
}

val seqOfIntsWithPosition = a.zipWithIndex.flatMap(vectorWithIndex => vectorWithIndex._1.zipWithIndex.map(intWithIndex => (intWithIndex._1, vectorWithIndex._2, intWithIndex._2)))
val sorted: IndexedSeq[(Int, Int, Int)] = seqOfIntsWithPosition.sortBy(_._1)
val element = sorted.search((4, dummy, dummy))
```

This code is not very pretty or readable, I just quickly wanted to show an example of how it could be done.

Comment: If I sort the data, then I lose the indexes.

Comment: I've added some code for sorting while keeping the indices

Comment: Unsorted algorithm is linear. Sorting is O(n*log(n)) ... What's the point?

Comment: Yes, this only makes sense if you can sort "off line" and then each query would just be `log(N)`. I realize that I was unclear about that. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Dima in the comments, the OP stated that the data structure could change, so sorting might be helpful.